# Relation of El Niño to Monsoons

Tags: meteorology, climate, enso

Scientists are forecasting a weak to moderate El Niño event to emerge in the coming months, what causes this to happen? Once developed, how will the El Niño conditions effect progressive monsoon systems?

Comment: There are a few regions that experience monsoons, are you curious about a particular region?

Comment: Possibly helpful http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qj.45/pdf