# Correlation of El Nino and south indian monsoon

Tags: meteorology, climate, climate-change, rainfall, monsoon

A recent [article](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn28595-massive-el-nino-sweeping-globe-is-now-the-biggest-ever-recorded) in New Scientist reports the following claim made by Wenju Cai at CSIRO Melbourne.

> Southern India is having a lot of rain as it goes into winter, having
>   come out of the dry monsoon. This is only so during extreme El Niño,
>   so it is a confirmation that the El Niño is huge

Does the claim indicate that a strong El Nino has a causal effect in extreme rainfalls in delayed monsoons? Has there been any historical evidence to backup this claim (for example the 1997-98 El Nino data)

Comment: Possible dupe of http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/relation-of-el-ni%C3%B1o-to-monsoons, but no answers there. Also, http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/oceanic-atmospheric-coupling-between-the-indian-ocean-and-the-pacific-ocean-basi, likewise

Comment: And maybe also related: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/what-causes-these-odd-looking-currents-in-the-tasman-sea  Hint: [Search the site](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+el+nino) before asking

Comment: @WanderingMind - The Southern Indian floods is not a case of delayed flooding. There are two separate monsoons in India. South West and North East. So onset was off by 6 days or so.